# Git remote add error when the repository's name has a ".git" suffix

Tags: git, version-control, ssh

When I push my local repository to remote server, I met with  "fatal: does not appear to be a git repository" error. So I searched the Internet, and found two possible solution:

Solution 1: [fatal: does not appear to be a git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7318918/fatal-does-not-appear-to-be-a-git-repository)

Solution 2: [git 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15437719/git-origin-does-not-appear-to-be-a-git-repository)

Solution 1 basically give some idea on how to write the URL correctly when using SSH protocol from your local repository while Solution 2 talks about the remote repository server.

I have used either of the solution. If I use the following git command to add a remote repository I will not have any problems:

```
git remote add Name ssh://XX@git2.company.com/export/git/Name
```

However, if I use the following command to add a remote repository (git remote rm Name first):

```
git remote add Name ssh://XX@git2.company.com/export/git/Name.git
```

I will have errors "fatal: Name.git does not appear to be a git repository" when the local repository is pushed to the remote server. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Why you’re using `ssh://`? Git uses SSH by default, there’s no need for that. However, first of all, there must be a colon between the hostname and the path. Try `git remote add UserName XX@git2.company.com:/export/git/UserName.git`. Btw, do you know that the name after `add` is not a username, but just arbitrary name of the remote repo?

Comment: @JakubJirutka Thanks, I have tried already, but failed.

Answer (score 1):

Whether or not you need the ".git" extension largely depends on the application used to host your Git repositories. Some of them allow the extension, some don't.