# fatal: does not appear to be a git repository when try to clone

Tags: git

I got these error messages when I try to clone from repo.

```
**Initialized empty Git repository in /Dir_Name/Sub_Dir/Repo_Name/.git/

fatal: 'drupal-Team/dreamcm.git' does not appear to be a git repository

fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly**
```

I'm using

```
**git clone git@git_url:drupal-Team/dreamcm.git**
```

I'm already visited here also, but got no luck
[fatal: does not appear to be a git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7318918/fatal-does-not-appear-to-be-a-git-repository)

Here is the output of git remote

```
git remote -v
origin  ssh://git@git_url:drupal-Team/dreamcm.git (fetch)
origin  ssh://git@git_url:drupal-Team/dreamcm.git (push)
```

Comment: I'm using linux server. It work fine when I clone in my local window machine.

Comment: I'm using git here first time.

Comment: Read about `git remote add origin url` . https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-remote/

Comment: How is it even possible to get output on `git remote -v`, when the repository isn't yet cloned? Have you used `git init` here?

Comment: Yeah I tried git init too. that's why I'm able to show the output.