# Git : Could not read from remote repository

Tags: git, ssh, git-remote

I'm trying to set a bare remote git repository on my ovh server. When I'm trying to push, I get the following error :

```
fatal: '/git/repo.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I've tried everything so far and that include every post on stackoverflow

- I've set a private/public key. It does not seem to be the problem. If I try with an invalid key, the message is not the same
- I've tried pushing directly from a repository on the server and it works
- I've tried setting chmod on the server to 777. No change
- I've tried to change the ssh agent, the message is the same
- this is my git configuration file

  ```
  [remote "origin"]       
  url = ssh://username@ssh.cluster014.ovh.net:/git/repo.git   
  fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
  puttykeyfile = D:\\Dev\\ovh-git.ppk
  ```

I believe this is a server configuration problem as I can push from the server on the server.

Note :

1. on the server, the git version is `2.1.4` and my local version is `2.18.0`
2. I've already tried the following SO posts

   - [git: fatal: Could not read from remote repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13509293/git-fatal-could-not-read-from-remote-repository?page=1&tab=active#tab-top)
   - [fatal: does not appear to be a git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7318918/fatal-does-not-appear-to-be-a-git-repository)
   - and many more...

Could you give me some input to find a way out?

Edit :
This is the output of `ls -ld` on the repository

```
drwxr-xr-x+ 7 username users 10 juil.  2 08:45 git/repo.git/
```

Comment: How (what specific commands did you run) did you create the git repository on your server? What is the output of `ls -ld /git/repo.git` on the server?

Comment: I updated the answer with the output of `ls -ld`. I created the repository with the command `git init --bare`

Comment: The issue here is clearly path-name-related. Be aware that when you ssh in, the *apparent* root starts at the home directory of the user, rather than the actual root. If you have the home directory of `username@...` set to `/git`, for instance, the appropriate URL would be `ssh://username@host/repo.git`.

Comment: Thanks @Torek, I came to the same conclusion. I tried with `/homez.166/user/git/repo.git` instead of `/git/repo.git` and it worked. Hourra! I spent 3 days on the svn migration. Thanks a lot for this last step!

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to set a git repository on an OVH server, the remote URL should be formatted like this:

```
url = ssh://username@ssh.cluster014.ovh.net:homez.xxx/name/git/repo.git
```